# Detect recurrent combinations through (lists) of vectors

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, associative-array

I have nested lists, let say:

```
data=list(a,b,d) #length of data can climb up to 50000 vectors
```

with

```
a=list(A,B,C,D) 
b=list(E,F,G)
d=list(H,I,J,K,L)
```

and

```
A=c(1,2,3,4) 
B=c(5,7,6)
C=c(8,9,10,11,12) 
D=c(13,14)
E=c(1,2,5,7) 
F=c(3,4,8,9)
G=c(11,13,2,8) 
H=c(2,3,5) 
I=c(4,7,8,11) 
J=c(5,9)
K=c(14,1,3) 
L=c(3,7,5,10)
```

I'm looking for a way to detect recurrent combinations of two (or more) numeric values within distinct a, b, d, vectors. Exemple: (1,5) appear together two times: in "a" ("1" in "A" and "5" in "B") but also in "d" ("1" in "K" and "5" in "H"). The (1,5) of "E" is not relevant.

Can I solve this with clustering or associations rules ? What is the best structure to give to these data ?

In advance thank you for your help.

Comment: So (1,5) and (5,1) are considered as two different combinations or the same?

Comment: You don't have nested lists here. `data` is one big vector, concatenated from the smaller ones.  That's not really what your problem is describing. Are you sure your example is right?

Comment: @ekoam You right, (1,5) is for me equal to (5,1)

Comment: @AllanCameron Your right, I updated the example.